# Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens

Tags: feature-request, design

In every page title on tex.sx, it says

> TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange

These horizontal lines between the words are hyphens (Unicode point U+002D "Hyphen-minus"). In proper typesetting, **these should be dashes**, either En Dashes (U+02013) "–" or Em Dashes (U+02014) "—". As I would say we're a community who cares about such details and who thus ought to be a role model for them, **I'd appreciate to see that changed**.

The difference between these three characters is directly reflected in (La)TeX by three distinct inputs, `-` (Hyphen-minus), `--` (En Dash), and `---` (Em Dash). A similar issue has been discussed at [New user greeting.](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/547/new-user-greeting), which now uses an Em Dash:

> Welcome to Q&A for users of TeX, LaTeX, ConTeXt, and related typesetting systems — check out the FAQ!

I'm not a big fan of the Em Dash, I think it interrupts text flow too strongly; nonetheless we should use dashes uniformly. Has anybody seen any other *proper* dashes around that would have to be adapted similarly? There are more pseudo-dashes (= Hyphen-Minuses) around here, e.g. after the title of a page, be it a question, "Frequently Asked Questions" or a user page:

> Putting a bar in the margin - TeX - LaTeX - Stack Exchange

So if you were asking me, I'd say we should use En Dashes on all occurrences of a dash (except one), with a regular space before and after it. Exception: It might make sense to use an Em Dash between a page title and the site title and En Dashes in the page title, like

> Putting a bar in the margin — *[= Em Dash]* TeX – *[= En Dash]* LaTeX – *[=En Dash]* Stack Exchange

This would reflect that there's a bigger "content break" between the first part and the rest than there is between the *TeX*, *LaTeX*, and *Stack Exchange*, but I don't know if that is a typographic no-no according to the one or the other typography bible.

Related questions (this will help with keeping everything consistent and preventing misinformation):

- [Correct hyphen to a dash in the "About" page](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3291/14996)  [meta]
- [How do I typeset the name of this site in (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98721/14996)  [main]
- [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/14996)  [meta]

Comment: Bringhurst argues for an en-dash in all of these cases, which would make life easier.

Comment: @JosephWright: Is that "easier than the status quo" or "easier than your recommendation about a combination of En Dahes and one Em Dash"?

Comment: @donchery: Easier than the mixed en- and em-dash suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Most web browsers do not, in fact, render HTML typographic entities in the `<title>` tag. Thus something like

`<title>Foo &ndash; bar baz</title>`

would show up in the browser as, literally:

> Foo &ndash; bar baz

That's why we avoid HTML entity characters in titles for the most part.

Comment: Can the web browsers StackExchange supports deal with Unicode characters in the `<title>` tag?

Comment: possibly, but it feels a bit hacky versus the proper HTML entity in the HTML

Comment: So, does this mean _status-declined_?

Comment: But you *are* implying that the title properly has an en-dash surrounded by spaces (or without spaces) instead of a hyphen. Could we get official word on the whether there are spaces around or not? This is relevant for [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3281/14996).

Comment: Unicode characters aren't "proper HTML"?

Comment: This is not correct, HTML entities work fine inside the `title` element. What doesn't work is `document.title = "&mdash;";` from JavaScript — use the literal Unicode character instead or use `\u2014` to encode the character.

Comment: I just [tried it out](http://chaos.stw-bonn.de/users/mu/uploads/2015-01-08/unicode-title.html) and it seems to work fine in Firefox and Chromium. Why can't we have proper dashes on a *site for typography*? HTML entities appears hackycompared to unicode to me, btw.