# Reputation tool-tip dash/minus ambiguity

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, reputation, user-profile-page

When looking at a user page and at "Reputation", hoovering the mouse over some day, then the tool-tip reads something like "Friday, Nov 25, 2011 - 42 reputation", which means "+42 reputation", not "-42 reputation". Would "Friday, Nov 25, 2011: + 42 reputation" (or maybe ";", "#", or whatsoever) not be more easily readable? (This format is used at other SE sites, too, probably everywhere.)

Comment: @doncherry: Done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like negative rep changes are not displayed in these graphs, it'll say "This user has no recent positive reputation changes". (Find a question with a negative score on http://meta.stackoverflow.com and go to its asker's profile to see that.)

But still, you have a point because people don't immediately know that only positive rep is displayed You should make your proposal at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112151/new-user-page-live, where all the feedback for the new profile is gathered. I like the colon : solution best, but if they don't see your point at all, you can still point them to [Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2008/use-dashes-in-page-titles-instead-of-hyphens) to demonstrate that the status quo is just unbearable `;)`.

Answer (score 2):

Status completed, issue solved:

[image: Screenshot]

> Yes, I can definitely see some confusion here, the format will use a :
>   instead of a `-` in-between the date and rep next build. – Nick
>   Craver♦ 2011-11-26 10:49:13Z

at https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113693/171937 (has been deleted as solved).

Comment: Why was it deleted?

Comment: Thanks for posting the deleted question - it documents the discussion for future reference.

Comment: @Werner: This is a one-for-all thread for feedback about the new profile and they said in the question: "We will be deleting posts with feedback that have made it to production to help keep things current."

Comment: @doncherry: Ah, then my guess "deleted as solved" was right. (It had been some time since I had read the question. Probably it is a good idea to read questions (again) before posting answers. Shame on me.) +1 for finding it.