# Correct hyphen to a dash in the "About" page

Tags: feature-request, bug, design

The official name of this site is "TeX - LaTeX", which is written with a hyphen at most places, this is obviously incorrect. I understand that in a page `<title>`, this is a common practice in HTML. But I think it could be corrected *in the text/body* of the [About page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/about), and the en-dashes `&ndash;` put there. If I didn't oversee anything, it is 4 times in that page.

Related questions (this will help with keeping everything consistent and preventing misinformation):

- [Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2008/14996)  [meta]
- [How do I typeset the name of this site in (La)TeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98721/14996)  [main]
- [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3281/14996)  [meta]

Comment: Closely related question, possibly even a duplicate: [Use dashes in page titles instead of hyphens](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2008)

Comment: @doncherry With the difference that in the About page, the dashes would work correctly as HTML entities ;)

Comment: You might have been meaning to link to [How do I properly cite TeX.SE for its help in typesetting?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/3281/14996), which I think reminded/motivated you of this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Outside of formal writing, I don't think think the careful distinctions between the use of hyphens and kinds of dash really apply, and even in formal writing, in this case I don't think you will find much in the way of clear guidance at all from style guides: here the equivalent of a running head is formed from a category (tag) and a title, a case where I think *Chicago* offers no sharp rules, and uses a colon for the task (see, e.g., 16th, p.843).  So I disagree that it "is obviously incorrect".

A purely pragmatic consideration against the change: dashes are larger than hyphens, and space is typically at a premium in browser tabs.  We would see a tiny little bit less of the title when we have many browser tabs open.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. My issue is not the page title, but the body.

Comment: @tohecz: Ah, sorry for being slow-witted.  That deals with the pragmatic consideration, but the punctuation still doesn't look "obviously incorrect" to me: compound names are made of smaller names either with hyphens ("William Rees-Mogg"), or en dashes ("Einstein--Podolsky paradox").  The issue is as much one of typography as lexical grammar, and as TeXnicians, we are surely not expecting HTML to do a great job.

Comment: I expect to squeeze out of HTML the best it can do without a serious over-cost ;)