# How do I stylize the logos for TeX, LaTeX, XeTeX, LuaTeX in an answer?

Tags: support

I want to write an answer on StackExchange using better styling for the names of the different TeX engines. The upper/lowercase approximation in text looks silly and unprofessional. (BaCtRiAnCaMeLCaSe?)

I had hoped something like `$\LaTeX$` would work, but nope.

I tried images, but it doesn't appear that I can make them inline with text. For example, this doesn't work [image: LaTeX] in the middle of a sentence.

I also tried HTML tags, sup and sub, to get L<sup>A</sup>T<sub>E</sub>X, but that is hardly better.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't: we don't have MathJaX enabled on the site, and there is a longstanding convention that outside of TeX systems, the 'proper names' can be written in simple mixed case. (This was once important for TeX itself, as there was a trademark issue with another system of the same name.)

Comment: Not only "once important".  It's *still* important.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10098

Comment: @barbarabeeton I meant that the likelihood of being sued by Honeywell has likely receded

Comment: While being sued is no longer likely, I see "tex" online and on shipping containers nearly every day, and "TEX" less often, but not never.  And I won't go into what happens when searching for "latex" online.  It's just a good idea to be careful and use the recommended mixed-case forms, however unattractive, when it's impractical to use the actual logos.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Please pardon me for showing my ignorance, but I thought Leslie Lamport didn't like the mixed-case recommendation and explicitly said that people can capitalize Latex in whatever way they like.

Comment: @hackerb9 -- I don't remember learning that Leslie said that, but it's true that a lot of people (myself included) don't really like CaMelCase.  But I feel that it's important to avoid confusion whenever possible, so will stick to the most clearly recognizable form of a name.

Comment: @hackerb9 Certainly Philipp Lehman (original author of `biblatex`) was of that view (as am I, really)

Comment: @barbarabeeton If you hadn't heard of it, then I will assume I am mistaken. Maybe I was conflating something else Lamport said, which was something like, _The hardest thing about LaTeX is how to pronounce it and I'm not going to tell anyone how to do that._

Comment: @hackerb9 -- But he *did* say something about that -- "Lah-TeX or Lay-TeX, anything but Ell-ay-TeX".  I've forgotten what year, but I was there when he gave an introductory presentation at a DECUS meeting in San Francisco.

Comment: Thank you, Barbara. You are a wealth of TeXnical knowledge.